# Use of asynchronous fetch function inside useEffect and rendering to page

Tags: reactjs, axios

Hello I have a question about fetch call inside componentDidMount. Here's an example code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ hits: [] });
  useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await axios(
      'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=redux',
    );
    setData(result.data);
  }, []);
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.hits.map(item => (
        <li key={item.objectID}>
          <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Here

```
useEffect(()=>{},[]);
```

This is the same as componentDidMount.

Inside useEffect we fetch data from server and store it into `data`. Then `data` is used to render items to page as `<li>` elements.

My question is, does fetch call (ie. axios) get executed AFTER `App` component gets mounted the first time? If so, how does `data` get populated in time for the first rendering?

```
<ul>
      {data.hits.map(item => (
        <li key={item.objectID}>
          <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
        </li>
      ))}
 </ul>
```

My understanding is, since `data` is populated AFTER the first mount, it won't be available for rendering?

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the difference between MOUNTING and RENDERING?

Can someone correct me because the above code obviously does work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's not populated, but the empty array still exists, so the code doesn't crash. When the component mounts and first renders, `data.hits` is equal to an empty array, `[]`. So you can map over it, but the length is 0 so the map won't produce anything. If initially you defined `data.hits` to be an empty object, or null or something, e.g. `const [data, setData] = useState({});`, THEN it would crash, cos initially `data.hits` is equal to `undefined`, and you'll get an error `Can't read property .map of undefined`

Comment: Just like Jayce444said useState starts with `{ hits: [] }` that's why your app doesn't crash. If you start useState with other than `{ hits: [] }` then all you have to do is put `data.hits && data.hits.map(...` and it wouldn't crash.

Comment: Does data get populated just before second render?

Comment: @logan Yes, `setData(result.data);` updates the state value of `data`, and that *causes* a second re-render (in both functional and class components, both state and prop changes cause a re-render))